# YouTube API returning 0 for live events even when event is currently livestreaming

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been using the following API call to check if public Livestream is currently active and it has been working fine for months. But today it is reporting 0 results even with the a current public livestream happening.

**API call:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCHHh4qGb0YDUvptCjBzal8Q&type=video&eventType=live&key=my_key
```

**Results:**

```
kind    "youtube#searchListResponse"
etag    "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/iw3ODF4UJzm6hue_kWNgTbK84vQ\""
regionCode  "CA"
pageInfo    
  totalResults  0
  resultsPerPage    5
items   []
```

**Expected results:**

When live event is streaming this normally should return totalResults of 1 (or more).

EDIT:

So after 40 minutes of livestream the API started reporting the live event. So I can only assume the API was somehow down and was not reporting properly and must be some kind of glitch/bug on the API end.

ANOTHER EDIT:

So there is definitely an issue with the API reporting. We ended the first public livestream event about 2.5 hours ago, and then started an new public livestream about 2 hours ago, but the API is still showing the first event as being live. Again it would appear to be some kind of glitch/bug with the API that is delaying the information by at least 2 hours or more.

Comment: Needs more information

Comment: @NiNisanNijackle What kind of further info do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think was happening, is that YouTubes API servers that provide the information about the livestream was somehow delayed.

So when the livestream started, it did not say there was a livestream until about 2 hours after it started, and then it continued to show that there was a live event for a couple hours after it ended.

Never got a response from YouTube so can only assume it was any issue with their backend.